# Exception in magento2 in fr_FR language

Tags: magento2, localisation

I have installed `fr_FR` package in magento2 site. But in detail page and checkout page I am getting error like below,

```
    [2018-03-24 13:10:46] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No localized value in 0.2750 found, or the given number does not match the localized format' in /home/Sites/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php:255
Stack trace:
#0 /home/Sites/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Measure/Abstract.php(202): Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber('0.2750', Array)
#1 /home/Sites/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Measure/Abstract.php(99): Zend_Measure_Abstract->setValue('0.2750', 'KILOGRAM', 'fr_FR')
#2 /home/Sites/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Helper/Carrier.php(92): Zend_Measure_Abstract->__construct('0.2750', 'KILOGRAM', 'fr_FR')
#3 /home/Sites/app/code/Custom/Shipment/Helper/AbstractHelp.php(609): Magento\Shipping\Helper\Carrier->convertMeasureWeight('0.2750', 'KILOGRAM', 'KILOGRAM')
#4 /home/Sites/app/code/Custom/Shipment/Helper/Data.php(73): Custom\ShipmentHelper\AbstractHelp->getConvertedWeight('0.2750')
#5 /home/Sites/app/code/Custom/Shipment/Model/Carrier.php(1922): Custom\Shipment\Helper\Data->getBoxForItems(Array)
#6 /home/Sites/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(293): Custom\Shipment\Model\Carrier->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
```

Due to this error shipping is not working please tell me any thing I need to add number format in that language csv file?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: @VivekKumar check now

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue with custom shipping method. The error was
**"No localized value in 0.3700 found, or the given number does not match the localized format"**
Afte debugging I found that there is an issue with a parameter which is passing in "**convertMeasureDimension**" function of Magento\Shipping\Helper\Carrier.
My Custom Shipping method uses the function of carrier class of Default Magento. There are three arguments of "**convertMeasureDimension**" function. In this argument, the first argument value type should be INT but I my custom shipping method it passing as a string so I have just change the type of the first argument as an INT and issue is resolved.